# Does Apple's SearchKit support sorting based on metadata?

Tags: cocoa, search, macos-carbon, spotlight

I know that searchKit allows you to use the spotlight importers to extract textual content from files for indexing, however, does it also allow you to extract all the metadata? I was reading that SearchKit only indexes [document content](http://phildow.net/2011/06/09/introducing-spsearchstore-an-objective-c-wrapper-for-searchkit/), and not even document name, but is there anyway to force it to get the metadata from spotlight importers and index those as well?

I also looked around inside the references but couldn't find any information on whether searchkit allows you to set a custom sortOrder for the results returned. Is this possible?